# What kind of Distribution describes the variance of Horse Racing results?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've seen people report the results of Monte Carlo simulations comparing the profitability of horses at 4/1 odds with 9/1 odds with 19/1 odds.

I believe it is erroneous to treat the probability of a 19/1 horse winning as if it were a 19 sided Cube, with each side having an equal opportunity of being landed on via random processes.

For one thing, research shows that horses going off at odds of 19/1 win much less frequently than that, and they are actually very bad bets.

For another, not all 19/1 horses are going off at 19/1 for the same reasons.  Some are legitimately that bad, and have no redeeming features.

Others are going off that high because there are extremely popular favorites in the race, the chances for which the Crowd had overestimated.

I am wondering whether certain statistical techniques might not be appropriate if a certain kind of distribution is assumed.

What distribution would best describe the results? Bernoulli? Binomial? Hypergeometric? Geometric?

I don't believe it is appropriate to assume that one could estimate such longshots to occur with any "regularity."

We have good reasons to believe that the probability of any number on a Roulette wheel will indeed occur 1 in 38 times, with equal frequency.

The same can not be said about horses.

I believe the Variance is such that a player could well lose 30 or 40 times before seeing a Win, and that Gamblers' Ruin is far more likely than Profitability with any "system" designed around counting on enough longshots to occur for a profit to occur.

Answer (score 1):

None of the considerations you mentioned affect how you should model a horse race. There are various reasons that a horse for which a bookmaker offers 19:1 odds of a win might win with some other probability than $\frac{1}{20}$. However, a single race would still only be a Bernoulli $\{0,1\}$ random variable, with whatever the true probability is.

If you want to consider several races, there would be a complex covariance structure, reflecting how performance in one race affects performance in future races (e.g. if the horse breaks a leg in one race, it won't win future races, so the events aren't independent). You might want to use the mathematics of time series, but I don't know enough about horse racing to know exactly what structure would be appropriate.

Comment: My question arose after somebody published a recommendation that contestants could win major handicapping contests simply by playing nothing but longshots at 19/1 odds. They did a Monte Carlo simulation about how often a Targeted Sum of Winnings would occur within 36 races, using horses at three different Odds levels. I think the results are invalid and the strategy recommendation is foolish because 19/1 winners simply do not occur frequently enough to win with such a strategy.  https://inthemoneypodcast.com/how-to-beat-the-best-in-the-world-at-the-nhc-with-minimal-work/